# Own Profiler in c++ messes up float return value from function

Tags: c++, memory, corruption, memset

I wrote a c++ profiler following to this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/800172/A-Simple-Cplusplus-Profiler-on-x?msg=4935639#xx4935639xx. Now I didnt copy it completely, just followed the general structure. This profiler is a dll that gets used in my other project. In that project, (as test case), I have a main function and a test function:

```cpp
float test(float in) { return in; }
int main() {
    float s = test(255);
    std::cout << "S: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is, that test returns 0 for data types float and double (if I replace every 'float' with 'double), but its fine with int, long and bool. Heres the code that the profiler is using

```
// this gets called from the DllMain function in the profiler
void create(void* pAddress) {
    ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_section);
    char moduleName[MAX_PATH];
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    VirtualQuery((void*)pAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
    GetModuleFileNameA((HMODULE)mbi.AllocationBase, moduleName, MAX_PATH);
    SymInitialize(GetCurrentProcess(), moduleName, TRUE);
    m_baseAddr = SymLoadModule64(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, (PCSTR)moduleName, NULL, (DWORD)mbi.AllocationBase, (DWORD) 0);
    SymSetOptions(SymGetOptions() & ~SYMOPT_UNDNAME);
    m_active = true;
    m_profiler = this;

    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    ::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    m_tickFrequency = li.QuadPart / 1000.0;
    m_lastTime = getCurrentCycle();

    std::cout << "Started in thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

// this finds the name of the function that was exited. Used both for entering and exiting (entering is disabled for testing)
void findFunction(void* pa, char*& funcName) {
    DWORD64 symDisplacement = 0;
    char undName[1024];
    if (m_baseAddr) {
        TCHAR buffer[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_SYM_NAME * sizeof(TCHAR)];
// if i comment out everything after this line, the returning works for floats too. Like this, it only works for ints and longs
        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        PSYMBOL_INFO symbolInfo = (PSYMBOL_INFO)buffer;
        symbolInfo->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        symbolInfo->MaxNameLen = MAX_SYM_NAME;

        //BOOL result = SymFromAddr(GetCurrentProcess(), (DWORD64)pa, &symDisplacement, symbolInfo);
        BOOL result = true;
        if (!result) {
            std::cout << "Could not get address: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        };

        // here Im checking whether this function gets called from differents threads, because apparently UnDecorateSymbolName can act weird when called from different threads, but the thread is always the same (the one that the create function was called from too)
        std::thread::id id = std::this_thread::get_id();
        if (id != threadId) {
            std::cout << "Changed thread: " << id << " from " << threadId << std::endl;
            threadId = id;
        }


        if (result) {
            //std::cout << "Calling from thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
            if (UnDecorateSymbolName(symbolInfo->Name, undName, sizeof(undName), UNDNAME_NO_MS_KEYWORDS |
                                     UNDNAME_NO_ACCESS_SPECIFIERS |
                                     UNDNAME_NO_FUNCTION_RETURNS |
                                     UNDNAME_NO_ALLOCATION_MODEL |
                                     UNDNAME_NO_ALLOCATION_LANGUAGE |
                                     UNDNAME_NO_ARGUMENTS |
                                     UNDNAME_NO_SPECIAL_SYMS |
                                     UNDNAME_NO_MEMBER_TYPE)) {
                //std::cout << "Name: " << undName << std::endl;
                if (!isStdFunction(undName)) {
                    strcpy_s(undName, symbolInfo->Name);
                    funcName = new char[strlen(undName) + 2];
                    //*funcName = std::string(undName, strlen(undName));
                    strcpy_s(funcName, strlen(undName) + 1, undName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// this is called from an assembler file in _pexit. Its working so far
void exitFunction(void* pa) {
    char* callee = nullptr;
    //const char* callee = "Hallo";
    findFunction(pa, callee); 

    __int64 endtime = getCurrentCycle();
    __int64 runtime = endtime - m_lastTime; 
    ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_section);

    if (callee) {
        /* leave out for now
        std::vector<HeFunctionData*>& stack = getStack();
        HeFunctionData* data = stack[stack.size() - 1];
        data->cycles += runtime;
        stack.pop_back();
        */
    } else {
#if HE_PROFILER_TRACK_STD
        // is std function
        __int64 now = getCurrentCycle();
        __int64 runtime = now - m_lastTime;
        m_data[GetCurrentThreadId()]["std"].cycles += runtime;
        m_data[GetCurrentThreadId()]["std"].calls++;
#endif
    }

    if (HE_PROFILER_TRACK_STD || callee) {
        m_totalTime += runtime;
        m_lastTime = getCurrentCycle();
    }

    ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_section);
    delete[] callee;
}
```

Now I debugged it to the point that if i comment everything after the `TCHAR buffer[...]` in findFunction out, it works as well. So the memset must somehow corrupt the return value of test() in the exe, if the data type is a float or a double. I am using Visual Studio 19 and both the dll and the exe are in debug mode. Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance,
unreal.

Edit:
As suggested in the comments, I replaced memset with my own "version" of it to set the array to zero. Now it works fine until the UnDecorateSymbolName function (if I leave it out, the return value is correct). It says that memory corruption can occur if the function is called from different threads, but that never happens. So why is UnDecorateSymbolName behaving like that? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Don't ever `memset()` `float`s or `double`s - it is *not* portable. A C++ implementation is *not* guaranteed to use IEEE 754 representation for floating point numbers and "all bits zero" may not always mean what you intend.

Comment: I dont directly memset floats or doubles, I memset a TCHAR array in the findFunction. What would be the better way to initialize that array to zero?